# How to convert a str that looks like a list to a list without the library ast

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I got a string that looks like a list in a `.txt` archive.
I want to convert this string to a list of list without the library `ast`, because I don't have permission to use that.

The string look like this:

```
string = "[['L', '1', '0', '0', '0'], ['2', '2', '0', '0', '0'], ['L', '2', '1', '1', '0'], ['1', '3', 'L', '2', '0'], ['0', '2', 'L', '2', '0']]"
```

And I want the literally list of this string. Pd: I use the typical loops and `.strip()` method, `.split()` method, but is very confusing. Help

Comment: `print( json.loads(string.replace("'", '"')) )` will help?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use eval(). As example:

```
string = "[['L', '1', '0', '0', '0'], ['2', '2', '0', '0', '0'], ['L', '2', '1', '1', '0'], ['1', '3', 'L', '2', '0'], ['0', '2', 'L', '2', '0']]"
string = eval(string)
print(string)
print(type(string))
```